# CSS not linking after server migration

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Hi and thank you for reading my post. I am currently having an issue where the css stoped linking for my subpages after migrating to a new server, the main page still links to the css but the rest of the pages are not linking anymore.

Here is the way my css is linkined on my header.php

```html
<link href="/_css/externship2018.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have tried everything but I am very lost and can't seem to make it work. The CSS worked well before moving but not it stopped working.

This is my doctype:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Thanks again.

Comment: open a Console and post the error

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "CSS not linking"?

Comment: There is really no error, its just the CSS not linking at all. You can see it on http://testexternships.jmls.edu/ - the main page works but the rest are misssing the css.

Comment: Please take a look at the site I posted above, literally the subpages wont connect to the CSS.

Comment: Where is your <head> buddy, you dont have it included in other pages... http://prntscr.com/kbs8ls

Comment: The entire `<head></head>` is missing from the sub-pages. Did you forget to add it back?

Comment: I check your page, the css-file is not INCLUDED

Comment: try to include the PHP-file of header

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am not being able to access the files anymore for some reason. As soon as I get access back I will add the <head></head> and link the css there.

Comment: Have you checked the path? Try to enter `http://yourwebsite.com/_css/externship2018.css` (or something similar) in the browser address bar. Does it work?

Comment: My question is, do the head tag needs to be included in all the subpages since I have a header.php file that has all the links? thanks!

Comment: As I am seeing I do actually have a <?php include($siteroot . "/_include/header.php"); ?> and a <?php include($siteroot . "/_include/footer.php"); ?> on all the subpages.

Comment: By the way, off topic, but why does your webpage have an XHTML doctype? Neither the file type nor the contents are XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `<head>...</head>` (and subsequently no CSS linkage) tags in the sub pages, also looks like you've no closing tags for the documents at all, so maybe there were supposed to be includes for these pages which are not in the right place now?

Comment: Thanks for the response, we had a developer that was working here before but it seems like she forgot to add some stuff or didn't have time. Can you please tell me like what documents I am missing the tags on? Thanks!

Comment: That's a little harder, unfortunately. Your source code doesn't render in the PHP it's been written in when I view it.

What you might find is that if you can download the php files of the sub-pages they will have something like `<?php include 'header.php';?>` which will indicate where the files were relative to the pages in the past.

Comment: Actually, having said that there, rereading the question you mention having 'header.php' somewhere. Basically, every page that isn't getting your CSS will be missing that header - it will need to be included in every page - they are all likely missing the footer as well.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, I see that the head is missing from all the subpages and I will be adding it and you are right also the footer is missing, I will be adding that too. I will let you know how that works out!